# isKindofClass for id

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code, which is pre-defined `NSArray` but I assign it to an `id` variable.

I display the output and want to display class name even though it shows `<__NSArrayI ..... >` on the output window, but I am getting an empty description as follows. How could I get class of `dic1` ?

```
id dic1 =@[@{@"id":@"1",@"name":@"Test 1 "},@{@"id":@"2",@"name":@"Test 2"}];

(lldb) po dic1
<__NSArrayI 0x100300090>(
{
    id = 1;
    name = "Test 1 ";
},
{
    id = 2;
    name = "Test 2";
}
)

(lldb) po [dic1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
<object returned empty description>
```

UPDATE

```
(lldb) p [dic1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
error: no known method '-isKindOfClass:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
```

Comment: What class name are you expecting? The class of the dictionary, the class of some element? what's the actual behavior you expect (I mean, what exact string you you expect lldb to print?)

Comment: Use `p`, not `po` to print non-object types.

Comment: @rmaddy, see the update

Comment: @RobNapier, I expect to see `YES` or `True`, because `dic1` is an `NSArray` object.

Comment: Why are you using `id` for `dic1` instead of its proper type?

Comment: Perhaps `p (BOOL)[dic1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` will work.

Comment: So not the classname at all. To print a BOOL, you need to use `p` (as @rmaddy) says, and because you're using `id`, you need to do what the error says: cast it.

Comment: Either @rmaddy's way, or I'm very certain it should work with `p [(NSObject *)dic1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`. Obviously this is one of many reasons not use `id`, but if `id` is unavoidable, then yeah, you have to cast a lot in the debugger.

Comment: @rmaddy, I am testing it to learn.

Comment: That's an excellent reason.

Comment: the casting `(BOOL)`, it worked. thanks a lot `Rmaddy` and `Rob Napier`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer that summarizes all of the comments.

1. Use `po` to print the result of an object type. Use `p` to print the result of a primitive type.
2. `isKindOfClass:` returns a `BOOL` so you need to use `p`, not `po`.
3. Since `dic1` is an `id`, the debugger isn't sure what the `isKindOfClass:` method is so it doesn't know its return type. Add a cast to make it clear:

   ```
   p (BOOL)[dic1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
   ```

   or you can also do:

   ```
   p [(NSObject *)dic1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
   ```
4. Normally you wouldn't want to use `id` for `dic1` but since this is a learning exercise, do what you want. :)